# Accessing DB with different Contexts

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-sqlite, android-context

I am fiddling with the db access in Android to see how things are handled.

I have the following code in my MainActivity.java file:

```
Log.v("test db acc", "start getApplicationContext test");
FileDbHelper dbHelper1 = new FileDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
SQLiteDatabase db1 = dbHelper1.getWritableDatabase();
Log.v("test db acc", "success getApplicationContext test");

Log.v("test db acc", "start getContext test");
FileProvider provider = new FileProvider();
provider.testDbAccess();
Log.v("test db acc", "success getContext test");
```

And this is the definition of provider.testDbAccess() function:

```
FileDbHelper dbHelper2 = new FileDbHelper(getContext());
SQLiteDatabase db2 = dbHelper2.getWritableDatabase();
```

First attempt of attempt to access the DB succeeds without any error. It creates the DB if it does not exists, and I can query and write data after creating the db1 object.

When I try to get writable database with `Context` returned with `getContext()`, it simply fails with a `NullPointerException`. It does not even start to create the database. Symptoms occurs even when I delete the code for `getApplicationContext()` test lines.

The problem in here is, I am trying to write code to get queries from database in `FileProvider`, and I cannot access the `getApplicationContext()` from that file (it simply raises a compiler error).

If I do all my process in MainActivity.java file I have no errors (which is not good I know, I did that only for testing purposes).

My questions are:

1. How and in which context should I create my database?
2. Why cannot I use the `getApplicationContext()` from `FileProvider`?
3. Can I access a database from another context which it was created in? To my knowledge, SQLite database is simply a file created in the android filesystem in app's own folder. What kind of difference is there for different `Context`s?
4. Why cannot I create a database in `FileProvider.java` with `Context` returned by `getContext()`?

**--EDIT--**

Here is the logcat for the error:

```
08-02 16:03:55.628 7614-7614/com.permasse.apps.file.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.permasse.apps.file.android/com.permasse.apps.file.android.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2575)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2603)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2089)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                at com.permasse.apps.file.android.FileProvider.testDbAccess(FileProvider.java:120)
                at com.permasse.apps.file.android.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:32)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1184)
                at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5082)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2565)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2603) 
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2089) 
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And here are the related parts of the FileProvider.java. Original code includes query builders, uri matchers etc. I have simplified the code to isolate the problem.

```
public class FileProvider extends ContentProvider {

    private FileDbHelper dbHelper;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        dbHelper = new FileDbHelper(getContext());
        return true;
    }

    public void testDbAccess() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); //Line no 120

    }

}
```

and MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        FileProvider provider = new FileProvider();

        provider.testDbAccess(); //Line no 32

    }
}
```

Comment: i am not sure what you are trying to do, but you can pass `context` to `FileProvider` class `...new FileProvider(getApplicationContext());` and use that `context` inside the method instead of `getContext()`, you can call getContext() or getApplicationContext() from a class that inherits a class that have them , like `Activity`  otherwise you have to pass it

Comment: What I basically trying to do is creating a provider, which will be tied to a loader later on. I like to create a database object within the provider class, it simply won't work (with getContext context). Same code works fine within MainActivity with getApplicationContext context. 
It is weird for me because in this application, it seems to work: 
https://github.com/udacity/Sunshine-Version-2/blob/sunshine_master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/sunshine/app/data/WeatherProvider.java
line no: 142

Comment: does your `FileProvider` class `extends ContentProvider` ?

Comment: Yes, indeed it does. I have even implemented the query method.

Comment: ok, now for the nullpointer exception, can you post the logcat ?

Comment: Just added them to question.

Comment: Do any of the AndroidManifest.xml entries affect how the context is being handled? Can it caused by the something missing in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I am not sure why it is how it is, but I solved the problem.

in my `FileProvider` class (which extends `ContentProvider`), if I try to `getContext()` anywhere else but `onCreate()` method, I get an empty context. That is why getting the db reference fails on my `testDbAccess()` method.

What I did is I declared a static `FileDbHelper` (which extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`) in my `FileProvider` class. Then in `onCreate()` method, I created the `FileDbHelper` class with proper context. Since it is static, I am now able to use this object later on anywhere in the same class. It looks a bit like this now:

```
public class FileProvider extends ContentProvider {

    // Create static FileDbHelper
    private static FileDbHelper dbHelper;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {

        // We can only access the context from onCreate() function, so we 
        // instantiate it here to use later on. 
        dbHelper = new FileDbHelper(this.getContext().getApplicationContext);
        // Important explanation about context in bottom of the answer!!


        return true;
    }

    // Then I can use it like this: 
    public void testDbAccess() {

        // dbHelper was staticly declared within class and instantiated already
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); 

        // Then do whatever you want to do with the code

    }
}
```

This also answers my questions:

**How and in which context should I create my database?**

- It does not matter in which context you create your db, you can access it as long as you can get a proper context.

**Why cannot I use the `getApplicationContext()` from FileProvider?**

- It turned out I can. Proper way of doing this is `getContext().getApplicationContext()` but you don't have to do that to get a reference to the db.

**Can I access a database from another context which it was created in?**

- Yes, you can create the db in `getApplicationContext()` and access it in `getContext()`

**Why cannot I create a database in `FileProvider.java` file with `getContext()` context?**

- Actually you can, problem was basically caused from not being able to access the context itself from the new test function that I wrote. Don't know why, but this is the situation :)

Hope it helps to someone else later on.

**UPDATE**

Important information about static objects and memory leak.

[m0skit0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/898478/m0skit0) warned me about memory leak that is caused by static objects which holds reference to context. Detailed information can be found [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.tr/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html). Briefly, it says

> If you plan on keeping long-lived objects that need a context,
>   remember the application object. You can obtain it easily by calling
>   Context.getApplicationContext() or Activity.getApplication().

So be careful about that one. Code snippet updated accordingly. This saved future me from a lot of headache :)

Comment: This looks like a nice solution (in fact we used this approach until it exploded on our faces) but unfortunately it is wrong. Never hold static references to `Context`. That will leak `Context`s (more details [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)).

Comment: What I hold as static is not a reference to `Context`, only to an object which extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` class. Yes, it gets the context as parameter, but itself is not Context.  Is it still wrong?
-- Pardon me, I am now reading the page you referenced.

Comment: Oh ok, I misunderstood you then. This phrase *"I created the `FileDbHelper` class with proper context"* confused me. Note that any class that also has an internal reference to `Context` will cause the same problem.

Comment: Ok, I readed the page you referenced, it says: 
_If you plan on keeping long-lived objects that need a context, remember the application object. You can obtain it easily by calling `Context.getApplicationContext()` or `Activity.getApplication()`._
What I understand from this is, it is OK if I create my `FileDbHelper` class with `getContext().getApplicationContext()`. This object is something that will not depend on activitieslifecycles anyway. It will start with app and app will use it until it gets destroyed. Am I right? :)

Comment: Right. You don't even need a parameter for `FileDbHelper` constructor anymore.

Comment: Well, it seems I cannot access the context within the `FileDbHelper` class, so I'll just leave it as it is and pass the application context to it as a parameter. I think that should work too, right? `FileProvider` class is going to be the only point that I am going to access it anyway.

Comment: I don't see how `Context.getApplicationContext()` would not work. It is a static call. Anyway do not trust yourself when you say *"FileProvider class is going to be the only point that I am going to access it anyway"*. That might not hold true in the future, and you will probably forget this discussion :)

Comment: Now that you argued that, challenge accepted and I bet that I will never forget it :) 
I will write a big, fat reminder comment for my future self :)
Thank you for all information you provided. Answer is now updated with your inputs and ready for self-acceptance within... 19 hours :)

Answer (score 1):

Even if you already answered your question I'd like to add some information.

The methods `getContext()` and `getApplicationContext()` can produce an `NullPointerException`, some times the classes just can't define what their own Context is, and in those situations, the APP will crash.

I think it's a good idea to explicitly pass the context to the `ContentProvider`. This way you can ensure that your app will not break.

For example:

```
public class FileProvider extends ContentProvider {
Context context = null;
public FileProvider(Context context){
 this.context = context;
}

// Create static FileDbHelper
private static FileDbHelper dbHelper;

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {

    if(this.context != null{
       dbHelper = new FileDbHelper(this.context);

    }else{
     // There is an error, notify the user and do something about it
     return false;
    }

    return true;
}

// Then I can use it like this: 
public void testDbAccess() {

    // dbHelper was staticly declared within class and instantiated already
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); 

    // Then do whatever you want to do with the code

}
```

}

and in you call just change 
`FileProvider provider = new FileProvider();`

to 
`FileProvider provider = new FileProvider(this);` for Activitys

or `FileProvider provider = new FileProvider(getContext());` for Fragments (witch always have a Context)

For the other questions: there's no difference in which context the database class is working. The context is in mostly to grant the Database helper access to the device.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. That is what I was going to do next if I could not figured how to correct this. Reason I insisted on correcting this one was that I saw this in a guide and I knew it works. I just wanted to figure out what was wrong with my code :)